# QGIS 3.8 label disappearance during XYZ Tiles generation

Tags: qgis, labeling

I make my own basemap with QGIS 3.8. On the map there are labels with X,Y coordinates. When I create XYZ export with QGIS processing tool, on the result some labels disappear.

What is the reason for that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like the export has some labels that aren't visible on the map canvas (eg La Chapelle). If your label placement isn't data-defined or fixed, QGIS kind of makes it up on the fly. Results may be different every time the map is rendered. Are you exporting at a different resolution than the map canvas shows?